# Inaccessable partition with 477GB

Tags: partition, storage

I recently installed Linux on my computer and the intention was to have a dual boot but that failed and wiped my disk of the Windows boot which isn't a big deal. However, I now have the unusable space from the Windows boot in this partition here. Is there any way in which I am able to reallocate the space within this partition to the current partition through either GParted or CLI?

`nvme1n1` is my existing partition in which Linux is working in and `nvme0n1` is the inaccessible partition which currently has the bulk of the storage space assigned.

[image]

[image]

Edits:

I had added `cat /proc/mdstat` and `dmsetup ls --tree` outputs

`cat /proc/mdstat`

[image]

`dmsetup ls --tree`

[image]

Outputs for `sudo dmsetup ls --tree`

[image]

Outputs for `sudo pvs`

[image]

Comment: delete and recreate the partition?

Comment: LVM install by default does not use entire volume for /. That gives the user an option to expand later if desired or add other volumes for data, systems or whatever. Do not use LVM but this has info on resizing, some other changes do not apply in your case. https://askubuntu.com/questions/262211/how-do-i-resize-an-encrypted-lvm-to-install-another-copy-of-ubuntu  & https://askubuntu.com/questions/3596/what-is-lvm-and-what-is-it-used-for

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`nvme0n1` is not a partition, it is an entire disk: "NVMe controller #0, namespace #1". Unless you have some serious enterprise hardware, your NVMe disks have only a single namespace on them.

`ataraid` as a filesystem type indicates you used to have a BIOS-RAID of some type, but your Linux installer overrode that and created a Linux installation on your second NVMe disk.

You seem to have `nvme0n1` detected as `/dev/md127` under the Linux software-RAID subsystem, with an `imsm` (Intel-style BIOS-RAID) superblock. To wipe that out, try:

```
sudo mdadm /dev/md127 --fail /dev/nvme0n1
sudo mdadm /dev/md127 --remove /dev/nvme0n1
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/nvme0n1 count=1024   #Be careful with this command!
```

I would also note that your swap area seems to currently be on an unencrypted partition, which might cause data leaks if the computer is stolen. If you are serious about the encryption, the swap should be encrypted too.

After getting rid of remnants of the BIOS-RAID setup, you might want to create one partition on `nvme0n1` that encompasses the whole disk. In GParted, that would mean selecting `nvme0n1` and then choosing `Device` -> `Create Partition Table...`. Then you should be able to create a partition on `nvme0n1` as usual, covering the whole disk. The new partition would become `/dev/nvme0n1p1`.

The next step would be to create an encrypted container on the new partition. Since you probably don't want to type your disk encryption passphrase twice, you might want to use `/etc/crypttab` on your encrypted root filesystem to hold the key for unlocking the second disk automatically. To do that, you would first create a key file containing e.g. 256 bytes of random data:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/cryptsetup-keys.d/  # makes sure the directory exists
sudo chmod 700 /etc/cryptsetup-keys.d # ...and is only root-accessible
sudo dd if=/dev/random of=/etc/cryptsetup-keys.d/cryptdata2.key bs=256 count=1
```

You would then initialize the encrypted container on `nvme0n1p1`, using the keyfile just created:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/nvme0n1p1 /etc/cryptsetup-keys.d/cryptdata2.key
```

It would be a good idea to add a "human-writeable" passphrase too, just in case the keyfile gets lost or damaged:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/nvme0n1p1  # enter a passphrase for the cryptdata2 container when prompted
```

Then you would add this line to your `/etc/crypttab` configuration file:

```
cryptdata2 /dev/nvme0n1p1 /etc/cryptsetup-keys.d/cryptdata2.key
```

(At this point, it would be best to rebuild your initramfs file, then reboot and verify that `/dev/mapper/cryptdata2` becomes available automatically. However, you didn't seem to specify the name of your Linux distribution, so I cannot give you exact instructions for rebuilding your initramfs - the required command is somewhat distribution-specific.)

Once you've confirmed that system will boot without errors and makes `/dev/mapper/cryptdata2` available automatically, the next steps would be initializing the encrypted volume for use with LVM:

```
sudo pvcreate /dev/mapper/cryptdata2
sudo vgextend data /dev/mapper/cryptdata2
```

At this point, the disk space of `nvme0n1p1` should be available for use by LVM, as indicated by e.g. `sudo vgs`. You could then use it to either create new logical volumes (with `sudo lvcreate ...`) or to extend existing logical volumes - even on-line, and including your root filesystem - with `sudo lvextend -r ...`.

But before extending the root filesystem to a second encrypted disk, I would recommend booting one more time and verifying that the system boots without errors with the second encrypted volume added to the default LVM volume group - just in case your distribution happens to have some problems dealing with a root filesystem on a multi-device encrypted volume group.

Comment: Currently getting a message when I attempt to make the partition on GParted saying that `/dev/nvme0n1p1 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!`